# Can I assign a full SQL statement inside a variable in Sybase?

Tags: sql, variables, sybase

I need something like this:

```
DECLARE @tax float
SELECT field1, field2,
CASE WHEN (@tax = select field3 from table2 where complex-sql-here) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE the-value-of-tax END
FROM table1
WHERE @tax = 'something'
```

I need to assign the value of the entire "select field3..." inside @tax. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You'll probably need Dynamic SQL but I'm not a Sybase guy, so I don't know for sure

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think you can´t assign a field to a simple variable.
You can use something like

```
Declare @temptable table (field3)
```

And now some service...

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is delclare your @tax variable  as character and concanete the result

declar @tax varchar(30)

select @ tax = convert(char,field1)+"," + convert(char,field2) ..

where ..

if you want to store sql statement simply u can store like

declare @sql varchar(1024)

select @sql =" write query here"

for execution

exec(@sql)